# detecting 500 internal server error using seleniumRC

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-rc, junit4, selenium-ide

How can you determine 500 internal server error using selenium RC?

I have tried to use selenium.isTextPresent(); method but it does not show or detect the occurring at all.

Comment: Are you referring to a 500 error for the main page or an additional resource loaded by the page? If it's the former then isTestPresent() should have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explore the use of the `captureNetworkTraffic=true` mode. This should enable you to log all response/requests stemming from a call, including HTTP 500s.

[Here](http://www.eviltester.com/index.php/2010/05/26/a-selenium-capturenetworktraffic-example-in-java/) is a link to get you started in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Try selenium.isElementPresent(locatorfor500error)